# Get Width of Uploaded image when upload complete using UPLOADIFY Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I want to get the width of an image when upload complete in uploadify and then make make the proportion correct with the previous one before upload

**FOCUS:** get the ***WIDTH*** of the uploaded image

Comment: What kind of action? On client or server side?

Comment: @Pekka on client side. make the proportion correct with the previous one before upload

Comment: Maybe add that to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//when all files finished uploading

```
'onAllComplete' : function(event,data) {
      alert("action");
    }
```

//when a file gets uploaded

```
'onComplete'  : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
      alert('There are ' + data.fileCount + ' files remaining in the queue.');
    }
```

try

```
$("#imgID").css("width");
```

or

```
$("#imgID").width()
```

it will look like

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
$imgThis=$(this);
alert($imgThis.width());
'onComplete'  : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {

        }
});
```

Comment: this is not my aim. HOW TO FIND WIDTH OF UPLOADED IMAGE??

Comment: this gives width of image after upload? but i want to know at the time of upload. Thus I can scale or transform or make some actions on it to maintain ratio with the image that was before this new uploaded image