# Are there any circumstances under which an image may not scale properly?

Tags: html, image

Let's say I have < img  src="http://www.always-going-to-be-absolute.com/images/thisimage1.jpg" width= "some px" /> (only a .jpg or .gif).  With only the width specified, are there any (any!) circumstances under which the height and width of the image may not scale accordingly, or may not scale at all, assuming there is no CSS or other code affecting it?  I can't think of any circumstances (and research doesn't bring up any), but I'd like to be sure by running this by some people who have more experience than I do.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No there are not. However, note that is it quicker to load an image of the correct size.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately I don't have that luxury.  Users will be able to submit an image and I will just be taking that src and applying a width to fit it properly on my page.  It would be heavier (and much more time consuming to build) to download the image and create my own properly sized image.

Comment: That will work fine, I'm just pointing out one extra point. If you have a lot of images to resize from/to the same size, XNview (free) lets you do batch resizing.

Answer (score 0):

If any other css code or anything else is not affecting it, then I don't think there should be a problem. Try using images of correct sizes though. Helps reduce loading time and preserve quality of images as well. Try it out and if you get any scaling or other problems, you know where to ask, right? ^_^

Comment: Of both the answers to my question so far, both have said to use images of the correct size.  In my site, users will be able to submit image URLs to be displayed, and I will just be changing the width to fit my page design.  Without downloading the image, isn't there no possible way to change image dimensions without using html?

Comment: OR, is there a way to at least determine the width of an image from a URL.jpg (if it's not specified in the html) without downloading the image?

Comment: you could write some server sided code which will allow users to crop their uploaded images to the dimensions required by you.....and then save it. You might have seen this on many websites where you upload your profile pictures. this helps with your scaling problem as well as image sizes will be reduced too. Also if you want to know the width of uploaded images, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186126/get-width-of-uploaded-image-when-upload-complete-using-uploadify-plugin

Comment: That "allowing users to crop images before uploading" thing I mentioned..........well check this out if you are interested - http://html5.sapnagroup.com/2012/08/preview-and-crop-before-upload/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're scaling the images through `width`. From [section 13.7](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#visual) of the HTML 4 specification:

> All IMG and OBJECT attributes that concern visual alignment and presentation have been deprecated in favor of style sheets.

I think the only two problems you may have here are:

Small images: If the image is 10x10px and is scaled to fit a 1000x1000px container, it will be pretty hard to make out what the image is supposed to be.

Thin images: If your container is 1000x1000px and the image is 250x25px, scaling the image to fit the container will result in a 1000x100px image.

> OR, is there a way to at least determine the width of an image from a URL.jpg (if it's not specified in the html) without downloading the image?

In front-end JavaScript you can simply:

```
img.clientWidth;
img.clientHeight;
```

On the back-end, PHP has a `getimagesize()` function which returns height and width. I imagine other languages also have similar functions.

Comment: Thanks, that's along the lines of something that may be helpful.  Reading the documentation of getimagesize, it says it will return those dimensions of the file.  Can that also work with a .jpg URL?

Comment: I imagine that would work for all `image/*` MIME types. jpeg is a very popular format, so I can't imagine it not working for jpeg files. :-)

Comment: OK, pardon my noob-ish ness here, but I was thinking that "file" was referring to something relative, like a file on my own server within the site.  Does "file" also refer to an absolute URL, for example a www.xyz.com/image.jpg?

Comment: It can take an absolute URL, yes. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php Example #3.

Comment: I was looking over that more and I didn't realize the image is downloaded for the function.  As far as page load time is concerned, would would downloading the image to alter the dimensions compare to just changing the dimensions in the html?

Comment: Well I figured it would be more downloading the image to first determine whether the images are an appropriate size. When a user uploads the image (I'm assuming that's what happens) you'll need to check it before scaling it - for the reasons mentioned in my answer.